# delete row from datagridview based on textbox value

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, mysql-workbench

I have a text box in a form that displays the id of the row selected. I want to add a query on delete button that deletes the row from the datagridview based on the textbox value. 
[image]

So far, my code for the delete button is:

```
 private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; password = pass; persistsecurityinfo = false; database = mapping; allowuservariables = false");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand commandDelete = new MySqlCommand("DELETE from products WHERE product_id = @proid_txtbx", con);
            commandDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proid_txtbx", product_ID);
            commandDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

It's not working.

Comment: When I click on Delete button, it just does not react to anything.

Comment: did you attached the event handler? button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click)? Should be done by the designer... Any more information or messages?

Comment: Debug your code and check what u r getting in product_id. If it is textbox id then use product_ID.Text

Comment: When I delete this record, it is deleting from the database, but how do I see the changes automatically in the datagridview?

Answer (score 1):

If product_ID is the name of your textbox you are missing the .Text at the end:

```
commandDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proid_txtbx", product_ID.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was due to this line:

```
MySqlCommand commandDelete = new MySqlCommand("DELETE from products WHERE product_id=" + @proid_txtbx.Text, con);
```

Thank you all for your help.